# lime vs phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, lime-unittest

I don't see this answered any where on the web, amazingly.

Unit tests in lime seem **so** much more simple to write than PHPUnit with all its extra boilerplate code.

Are there any definitive reasons (besides "PHPUnit is the defacto standard") for choosing one over the other?

Comment: Keep in mind that lime has been developed for/with symfony and since symfony2 will use phpunit and drop lime, I'm not sure how the future of lime is.

Comment: K, i don't really care what it's future is. I am more interested in technical reasons.

Comment: Ack! The Close Brigade strikes again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHPUnit is more Object oriented than lime, I mean in the way you write your unit tests code.
PHPUnit has more functionalities ( think Selenium integration and xUnit output standards ).

Lime seems more simple with simple test cases, but when you tests are growing, it's unreadable.

I've used both, and I have no regret with the switch to Phpunit.

Moreover, for technical reasons, you *should* take care of the future of lime.

For info, Lime2 has been written by Bernhard Schussek, but to my mind, dev has been stopped since Symfony2 is using phpunit.

Comment: +1. Though the emphasis could as well have been "Moreover, for technical reasons, *you* should take care of the future of lime". (I.e. if you like it so much, take responsibility for maintaining lime or face bitrot over time.)